# Running command for Linux from Java runtime

Tags: java, linux, unix, gpgpu, gnupg

Can anyone help me how to run a gpg encryption command from a java program using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

sample command which I wanted to run shown below:

***gpg -u 'receipient' -r KeyID --armor --output /home/myuser/tmp/check.pgp --sign --passphrase '*&sw@217' --batch --encrypt /home/myuser/tmp/check.txt***

When I try to execute this from my Java program it gives error like "usage: gpg [options] [filename]"

Please help on resolving this error and run the above gpg command from a java program.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Have you tested the command itself?

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  Also, no one can troubleshoot your code if you don’t show your code in your question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is due to `.txt*`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should solve your problem if the `gpg` binary is correctly installed on your host.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("gpg -u 'receipient' -r KeyID --armor --output /home/myuser/tmp/check.pgp --sign --passphrase '&sw@217' --batch --encrypt /home/myuser/tmp/check.txt*".split(" "))
.inheritIO()
.start();

p.waitFor();
```

I haven't the correct settings but this code runs as expected. You can try it here: https://tech.io/snippet/VzJtME0